# Newbie question about 'jq' tool for json - how do I create a query for this?

Tags: json, jq

Please help a JSON / jq newbie. I have a JSON-file that looks something like this:

```
[
   {
        "name": "my_comp_1",
        "desiredVersions": []
    },
    {
        "name": "my_comp_2",
        "desiredVersions": [{
            "name": "1.0",
            "component": {
                "name": "my_comp_2"
            }
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "my_comp_3",
        "desiredVersions": [{
            "name": "1.1",
            "component": {
                "name": "my_comp_3"
            }
        }]
    }
]
```

I need to create queries like:
What is the version for 'my_comp_2'
which in the example should give me '1.0'
I have figured out how to take variables from commandline, but not the jq-query itself. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to pass a value to [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) on the command-line is to use the `--arg` option. Here, I created the variable `$name` containing `my_comp_2`:

```
$ jq -r --arg name my_comp_2 '
  .[]
  | select(.name == $name)
  | .desiredVersions[].name
' file.json
1.0
```

`-r` outputs the "raw" value, without the enclosing double quotes.

Comment: "Thanks" on StackOverflow = Accept / Upvote ;-)